# Java decompiler jd-gui is not working

Tags: android

I am extracting source code of an apk file using [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file).
I am getting problem with Java decompiler jd-gui, whenever I tried to open code in Java jd-gui, it stopped working.
Is there any other optional decompiler available?

Comment: follow this process: http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

Comment: Padma,i have done that process,after that process when i got classes_dex2jar,then we need a decompiler(like-jd-gui) to show all Java files,my decompiles stops working each time at middle of the process.Please suggest me,what to do now?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an apk and you want the source. Here is the process:

First  you need the jar that is inside the apk using dex2jar in that way:

> ./dex2jar.sh name.apk

Download dex2jar from: http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/
Once you have the jar you can use jad to extract the source with this command:

> ./jad -o -r -sjava -dsrc path/to/**/*.class

Download jad from: http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/

Notice that if the apk is using proguard the code will be ofuscated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal and has happened to me too.The issue is beacause of the advertisements.

Create a new Jar file containing only the classes without the ads and jar them together from the command line using

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

You can substitute the entire directory as an inpot file and it will jar it recursively for you. Now use jd-gui and open up the new jar file and it should work.